# What are the effects of Satan's action with the Book of the Dead?

Tags: disenchantment

In the very last episode of *Disenchantment*, Satan (or apparently, Satan junior) returns to Hell and as his first action he opens the Book of the Dead and

> strikes out the names of Bean, Mora the Mermaid and Lucy.

Does it mean that those people are immortal, can't get to Hell or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Via https://disenchantment.fandom.com/wiki/Book_of_the_Dead:

> [Book of the Dead] is used by Satan to keep track of all people send to Hell, or that will be send to Hell.

> In the season 5 finale Goodbye Bean, Satan, after being freed of Queen Dagmar, is seen visiting the book. He searches the names of Bean, Mora and Lucy, and erases them from the book, thus ensuring none of them will ever be send to Hell.

He crosses their names to ensure they won't end up in Hell.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to confirm my theory. I should have asked what "The book of the dead" really is.
Also, welcome to the site!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This would be a stronger answer if you quoted the original sources.

Comment: @DavidW the wiki quoted has a screenshot of the episode, with Luci explaining The Book of the Dead.